# Rails Runner throwing: undefined local variable or method `app' for main:Object (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I got a working Rails App (3.1.1). Now I wrote a runner (saved in app folder).
When starting the runner with:
rails r app/delete_old_addresses.rb

it dumps:

/Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:49:in `eval': undefined local variable or method`app' for main:Object (NameError)
    from /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:49:in`'
    from /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:63:in `require'
    from /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:63:in`'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in`'

Any ideas why? My Webapp works perfectly fine.

The runner looks like this:
class DeleteOldAddresses < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Comment: My bad, should be starting the runner with
rails r app/runners/delete_old_addresses.rb

Comment: Running with relative path might be an issue, try full path instead.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue. Running rails runner on `my_script.rb` (in my script folder, which I created on the same level as the `app` directory in Rails 4.0.0) directly gave me this error. When I ran `rails runner script/my_script.rb` it worked.